# Selecting the last year for each index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have this dataframe:

```
         score    year ...
index    
0        123      2015
0        5354     2016
0        4314     2014
12       4542     2018
12       4523     2017
13       123      2014
13       123      2012
13       231      2016
...
```

I want to select only the last year for each index, so it gets to look like this:

```
         score    year ...
index    
0        123      2016
12       4542     2018
13       231      2016
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
In [188]: df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, 'year'))
Out[188]:
        score  year
index             
0       5354  2016
12      4542  2018
13       231  2016
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [193]: df.sort_values('year', ascending=False).groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).head(1)
Out[193]:
       score  year
index             
12      4542  2018
0       5354  2016
13       231  2016
```

Answer (score 3):

Use drop duplicates i.e

```
ndf = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates('index',keep='first')
```

If year is unsorted then

**Using sort_values and drop duplicates**:

```
ndf = df.reset_index().sort_values('year').drop_duplicates('index',keep='last')
```

or

```
ndf =df.reset_index().sort_values('year',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('index',keep='first')
```

Output:

```
   index  score  year
1      0   5354  2016
3     12   4542  2018
7     13    231  2016
```

Comment: good point. in the above example I stated them as always being the first but the point is that sometimes they are not the first, it can be mixed. I will edit it.

Comment: I'm getting KeyError: 'index' :/ you know what that could be?

Comment: try doing it with `df.reset_index().sort_values...` I thought `index` is a column

Answer (score 0):

By using `idxmax`

```
df=df.reset_index()
df.loc[df.groupby('index').year.idxmax()].set_index('index')

Out[148]: 
       score  year
index             
0       5354  2016
12      4542  2018
13       231  2016
```